# separate click on each item in android

Tags: android

The question might be duplicate ..sorry for that.

I have an activity (test activity) and array adapter (test array) for same.
The list contains image and text. but the image is not displayed always. It has some condition. So look is like

```
---------------------------------------
image1 text1

          test2

          test3

image4    test4

---------------------------------------
```

So test activity display the above list on screen.

Now i want to do different screen load on image (image activity) and text (text activity).
As the on-click handler will be in separate file (test array) i am not sure how to return to test activity and to specific task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i have a list view with image and text.
Below are some scenario

Image will not be present on each row.
If image is present then Onclick of image shown other screen (for example image activity).
if user click other than image that is text show text activity screen).

What i have done is i have a list click handler in a separate file that is ArrayAdapter so i cant't do image click listener there.

So the issue was how to identify which row image is clicked?

Solution:

After lots of R&D and code changes i done below and its working:

I have added android:onClick="ImageClickHandler" for image click in xml.
and during row creation i have set row position as Id.
So when clicked on image you can get position by view.getId(), so u have the position when u click on image and hence you can get complete data on that row.

Might be there is another way....but this is what work for me.